puppet failing to update
Getting a strange problem that I have not seen before.  Didn't see in lower environment but typically only in production.
Trying to update mysql from version x to version.
level: :err
message: 'change from 1.1.1.el7 to 1.1.2.el7 failed: Could not update: Failed
to update to version 1.1.2.el7, got version 1.1.1.el7 instead'
In terms of puppet code I have I have manifests\init.pp with below...
$mysql_community_common=hiera('mysql_community_common')

then lower down in same init.pp
package { "mysql-community-common":
    ensure => hiera('mysql_community_common')
  } ->

I have a hieradata\default.yaml file containing the actual version
mysql_community_common: "1.1.2.el7"
Any help or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance

Which version? I only see version like 8.x...  (https://pkgs.org/download/mysql)

This is an issue with the package manager and the subscribed repos on the system. You would want to begin investigating there.

Thanks.  I found that the applicable repo was in disabled state

... which, of course, is itself something that you can manage with Puppet.  And which you probably should manage if your manifests rely on  it.
